# Why Earth & Sky won't acccept Bhishma?

Tags: mahabharata, bhishma

As per Mahabharata, Bhishma said to Arjun, to lay him in middle, as Earth & Sky will not accept him.

1. What's the reason behind Earth & Sky not accepting Bhishma?
2. Is there some conditions to be accepted by Earth & Sky after Death?
3. Also there are a lot of questions arising out of both the Great Epics - Ramayana and Mahabharat. Is it that the details are not mentioned properly in the Epic or we are unable to find out the details required for these questions?

Please do provide more details. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I do not know of any such wish of Bhishma; you can read the relevant chapters [here](http://sacred-texts.com/hin/m06/m06120.htm), [here](http://sacred-texts.com/hin/m06/m06121.htm) and [here](http://sacred-texts.com/hin/m06/m06122.htm).

Comment: Check https://www.quora.com/Is-there-any-story-like-any-curse-behind-Bheeshma-laying-on-a-bed-of-arrows-at-war

Comment: Your question #3 is not making much sense, you should probably delete it or ask that in a separate question. Also, you should remove the Ramayana tag since this question is about Bhishma.

Answer (score 1):

Bhisma vowed not to get married (Bhisma pratigya) thus was never a father. As per Hinduism, once you are born it's one of your dharma (duty) to become a father. Pitradharma.

Comment: Explain your answer regarding the question "not being accepted by Earth & Sky". Visit [answer] and cite some sources.